# (SQL) Select all if ID = 0

Tags: sql

im still very unexperienced with SQL, so this might be a stupid question.

Let's say I have a Statement something like this:

```
SELECT * WHERE table_menu.year = @year
                            AND table_menu.user = @user
                            AND table_menu.history = 'false'
```

@user would be a Number from 0 - 100 how would I manage to get a table with all the Table contents if the user was 0?

Comment: The question is unclear, what prevents you from setting `@user` to 0?

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear. @user is set to 0. but none of my table contents has 0 as user. So if it is 0, it's supposed to select all the table contents while still considering table_menu.year and table_menu.history

Comment: You write your application to not include the `AND user = @user` line in your statement, for such cases. Do not fall in to the trap of trying to write one statement for all cases. It can utterly kill performance (because your one statement gets compiled to a single Plan to suit all cases, but you want different plans for different cases).

Comment: @MatBailie What should I use instead?

Comment: As I said, your application code should build a SQL statement without the user filter in the where clause, when the application sees that @user is 0.  *A very detailed article (sql server specific, but generalisable to all dialects) explain the options and the pros/cons : https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html*

Comment: I'll read through that, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either do that on client-side, so where you set the sql-parameter. If you know that user is 0 which should be treated as "all users", then simply select all from table_menu:

```
SELECT * FROM table_menu
WHERE table_menu.year = @year
AND table_menu.history = 'false'
```

or you could do that in the database, maybe with a performance impact:

```
SELECT * FROM table_menu 
WHERE table_menu.year = @year
AND (@user = 0 OR table_menu.user = @user)
AND table_menu.history = 'false'
```

Comment: Certainly with a performance impact. I strongly recommend the former approach; use code to build / adapt / pick SQL Statements specific to the use case, rather than cramming one statement full of use cases that would ideally utilise different indexes.

Comment: To clarify: I have a Dropdownlist, which allows me to pick a User to view his Information. So if I select 0, I want to have all of them displayed at once

Comment: @BlankMind: Does it matter?

Comment: @BlankMind And then the code in php or visual basic, or some database-side stored procedure, or whatever language, should check if the drop down selection is 0 or has no selection. Then that code can write / build / chose the first SQL Statement given here, rather than trying to utilise a single SQL Statement that tries to cover all circumstances.